# Avoid animation while scrollToItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need a collectionView to scroll to selected index without animation. While in method i am using animated as NO. It is taking animation after passing NO into it. Please help me if anyone has an idea about it.

```
[self.firstCollPView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:selIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try to perform this on main thread if it can solve issue! Something like,

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.firstCollPView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:selIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];

});
```